# Calculating R value for ANN predictions using stats in python

Tags: python, pandas, scipy.stats

I have implemented ann for regression using tensorflow keras on a dataframe. I am trying to calculate different accuracy metrics for the predictions. Following is the part of the code I have used for calculating the accuracy metrics.

```
    ypred = model_sel.predict(xscale_val)
    ypred1 = scaler_y.inverse_transform(ypred) 
    print("x")
    plt.plot(yact.values)
    plt.plot(ypred1.tolist( ))
    # plt.show()
    ANN_RMSE = sqrt(mean_squared_error(yact.values,ypred1.tolist()))
    ANN_R2 = r2_score(yact.values,ypred1.tolist())
    ANN_MAE = mean_absolute_error(yact.values,ypred1.tolist())
    print("type",type(yact),type(yact.values),type(ypred1),type(ypred1.tolist()))
    print(yact.values)
    print("pred",ypred1.tolist())
    ANN_R = stats.pearsonr(yact.values,ypred1)
```

I am not able to get the pearson correlation value for the predictions. I am beginner in python, it would help me if you can provide information on what I am doing wrong and how to correct this.

following is the error, Iam seeing.

```
  File "c:\Users\DELL\journalPub\models.py", line 166, in ann_model_results
    ANN_R = stats.pearsonr(yact.values,ypred1)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 4034, in pearsonr
    xmean = x.mean(dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 160, in _mean
    ret = umr_sum(arr, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc add
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by doing the following modifaction to the code:

```
ANN_R = stats.pearsonr(yact.values.flatten(),ypred1.flatten())
```